# Using jQuery to reference form fields in an Array

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have an HTML form that looks something like this:

```
<td><input type='checkbox' id='a[] '><input type='text' id='b[]'></td>
<td><input type='checkbox' id='a[] '><input type='text' id='b[]'></td>
```

Within a jQuery function I would like to enable / disable the associated input text input - b when the checkbox is clicked.

I am unsure how I can reference each field individually within a jQuery .click() function when using an array.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar concept to Thomas, but executes on page load and throws in a .focus() for good measure:

```
$(function(){
    var toggleState = function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked'))
            $(this).next('[name="b"]').removeAttr('disabled').focus();
        else
             $(this).next('[name="b"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
    };
   //bind event and fire off on page load
    $('input[name="a"]').bind('click',toggleState).each(toggleState);
})
```

Also, you shouldn't have duplicate ids... use the name attribute or target by classes.

```
<table>
 <tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='a'><input type='text' name='b'></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='a'><input type='text' name='b'></td></tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R28dV/4/

Comment: Cheers Derek. I have since changed it to targed by class. I noticed you removed the [] from the name, which is my biggest problem. Is it possible to do this while still using the array?

Comment: Yeah, if you are going to target by class you can keep the name as an array. You can probably target by the name attribute with the array brackets, but I believe it's more efficient to target by class name anyways. Check original jsfiddle link for updated code to utilize class targeting [http://jsfiddle.net/R28dV/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/R28dV/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this (i'm sure there's a more concise way but i don't have IntelliSense in here lol)

```
$("checkbox").click(function(){
 if($(this).next().attr("disabled") == "disabled") {
$(this).next().attr("disabled", "");
}
else {
$(this).next().attr("disabled", "disabled");
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `disabled` attribute to enable an input.  Set the `disabled` attribute to any value, customarily "disabled", to disable an input.  Setting `disabled=""` is not good enough, the mere presence of the attribute disables the input.  You have to remove the attribute.

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function()
{
    if (this.checked) $(this).next().removeAttr("disabled");
    else $(this).next().attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid if you have duplicate IDs. Give them unique IDs so your HTML is valid again, and your problem is also solved.